# Methods for finding $\cos(4x)$ given that $\sin(2x) = \frac{3}{5}$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin(2x) = \frac{3}{5}$

Find $\cos(4x)$..

I tried by : $\cos(4x)= \cos(2\cdot2x)$..

And $\cos (2\cdot2x) = 1-2\sin^2(2x)$ ..

From it ---- $\cos(4x)=0.28$.

Is there any other ways ?

Comment: That's the most direct one, in my opinion.

Comment: Looks fine to me since the answer is $\frac{7}{25}$ which is $0.28$ (except your formatting)--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Form the 3-4-5 triangle.
2. Reflect it about the "4" side. to get a 5-5-6 triangle.
3. apply the cosine law to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems the 'obvious' way. However you asked for other ways so here is another.

Given $\sin2x=3/5$ you can see from the right angled triangle with opposite $= 3$, hypotenuse $= 5$ that the adjacent side $= 4$ and so $\cos2x=4/5$

Knowing $\sin2x$ and $\cos2x$ you can determine $\sin4x=2\sin2x\cos2x=24/25$

These values are the opposite and hypotenuse of another nice triangle whose adjacent side $=7$. Hence $\cos4x=7/25=0.28$